# Need help with a determinant proof.

Tags: matrices

Prove that if $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} \;\; =\;\; 0
$$

for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, then $\det A = 0$.

So far I've been able to interpret that the rows sum to $0$,
but I'm stuck after that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find an obvious eigenvector which has eigenvalue 0.

**Hint:** Recall that the determinant of a matrix is equal to the produce of it's eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Using row reduction, the determinant of $A$ is equal to the determinant of $B$, where $B$ is the matrix you get by adding all other rows to the last row.  And the determinant of $B$ is zero because . . . .

Comment: How would this work, because the sum only gives us the fact that the individual rows sum up to 0, so what would adding them to the last row do?

Comment: It works because the individual rows sum up to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be the columns of $A$. We are given that
$a_1+\cdots+a_n = 0$ and so $a_1 = -(a_2+\cdots+a_n)$, that is, the columns are
linearly dependent. Since $\det$ is alternating, it follows that $\det A= 0$.